# R - windowing data backwards from latest data in non-overlapping (not-rolling) periods and counting within periods

Tags: r, datetime, time, tidyverse, lubridate

The problem I am looking to get insight on is regarding counting totals and subtotals in R in non-overlapping regular periods going backward in time.

Generating this example data frame,

```
library(lubridate)

set.seed(1)

dates <- ymd(parse_date("2023-12-31") - days(0:199))

colors <- c('red', 'blue')
sample_colors <- sample(colors, 200, replace = TRUE)
objects <- c('pen', 'marker', 'brush')
sample_objects <- sample(objects, 200, replace = TRUE)

test_df <- data.frame(dates, sample_colors, sample_objects)
```

I end up with something like this:

```
> head(test_df)
       dates sample_colors sample_objects
1 2023-06-15           red            pen
2 2023-06-16           red         marker
3 2023-06-17          blue            pen
4 2023-06-18           red            pen
5 2023-06-19          blue            pen
6 2023-06-20          blue          brush
```

Say I want to count the number of the least common color-object grouping every 60 days (e.g. blue brush, red pen, etc.) going backwards. I'll start without the requirement to go backwards and turn to the `slider` package. I would proceed with

```
period_count <- function(data) {
  summarise(data, 
            earliest_day_of_period = min(floor_date(dates, "day")),
            latest_day_of_period = max(floor_date(dates, "day")),
            sub_total = n(),
            .by = c(sample_colors, sample_objects)
  ) %>%
    summarise(
      earliest_day_of_period = first(earliest_day_of_period),
      latest_day_of_period = first(latest_day_of_period),
      day_span = first(latest_day_of_period) - first(earliest_day_of_period),
      min_object_n = min(sub_total)
    )
}

test_df <- test_df %>% arrange(dates)

test_df_period_counts <- slide_period_dfr(.x = test_df,
                                         .i = test_df$dates,
                                         .period = "day",
                                         .f = period_count,
                                         .every = 60,
                                         .complete = TRUE
                                         )
```

(I know `across()` is being deprecated by the way, so apologies for the outdated usage. Just haven't gotten experienced with the `reframe()` syntax yet.)

The `slide_period_dfr` operation gets me this,

```
> test_df_period_counts
  earliest_day_of_period latest_day_of_period day_span min_object_n
1             2023-08-14           2023-09-15  32 days            4
2             2023-09-20           2023-11-10  51 days            6
3             2023-11-19           2024-01-10  52 days            4
4             2024-01-18           2024-02-24  37 days            6
```

which leaves me confused, as no period appears 60 days long, and there are two shorter partial periods bookending the middle, longer ones. Perhaps the way that I am fetching my first and final days of each period are incorrect.

But, assuming the dates presented above are correct, what I want to do is to instead start complete period formation from the last day going backward, such that the partial period/window is in the beginning rather than at the end. I want a full 60 day period going backward from `"2024-02-29"`, and so forth, until a full period is no longer possible, and then it should be discarded. Also, even though I have set the `.complete` argument in `slide_period_dfr` to `TRUE`, operations are still happening on partial-sized periods (which is all of them!). If anyone could let me know what I am doing wrong to compel calculations to still occur for these partial windows, please let me know.

So, in summary, is it possible to do exact period creation with the `slider` package in the backward direction, or will I need to go with a different package and implementation method? Thank you for your help.

Comment: If a combination doesn’t appear at all during a given period, should `min_object_n` be 0 for that period? Or should it reflect the least prevalent of the combinations that do appear?

Comment: PS - I would hard-code a specific date into your example rather than `today()`, to keep your reprex consistent over time.

Comment: @zephryl Thanks for the suggestions! I'll edit with a specific date. In terms of the actual use, I would be still looking for the least prevalent of the combinations that do appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two things going on here:

1. You need to set an origin date. From the [docs](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/slider/html/slide_period.html), *This is generally used to define the anchor time to count from, which is relevant when the* `every` *value is ⁠> 1⁠*
2. Your function `period_count()` function has some errors. If you `group_by(sample_colors, sample_objects)` when calculating the date span for entire period, you'll get different dates for each group, and the apparent length of the period will be calculated from the min and max dates for the object with the fewest appearances, rather than all the objects in the period.

But we can simplify the `period_count()` function somewhat:

```r
period_count  <- function(dat) {
    dat |>
        add_count(sample_colors, sample_objects, name = "sub_total") |>
        summarise(
            earliest_day_of_period = min(dates),
            latest_day_of_period = max(dates),
            day_span = latest_day_of_period - earliest_day_of_period,
            min_object_n = min(sub_total)
        ) 
}
```

Together with supplying the `.origin` this produces non-overlapping periods starting from the end:

```r
slider::slide_period_dfr(
    test_df,
    .i = test_df$dates,
    .period = "day",
    .f = period_count,
    .every = 60,
    .complete = TRUE,
    .origin = max(test_df$dates) +1
)

#   earliest_day_of_period latest_day_of_period day_span min_object_n
# 1             2023-08-15           2023-09-03  19 days            1
# 2             2023-09-04           2023-11-02  59 days            5
# 3             2023-11-03           2024-01-01  59 days            6
# 4             2024-01-02           2024-03-01  59 days            6
```

Comment: Thank you for discovering the errors in `period_count`. My remaining unresolved matter relates to the ignoring of the `.complete = TRUE` with counts being tallied for the partial period. Is the partial period not being dropped a sign of a bug in the "slider" package itself?

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug or if `slide_period_dfr()` is expected to work differently to `slide()` over a vector, but yes it seems odd to me that you get identical output regardless of whether the `.complete` parameter is `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: And one last question, why is the 1 summation needed for the `.origin` setting? Is the computation incorrect if simply starting the `.origin` from the latest data date?

Comment: The origin date doesn't seem to be inclusive so if you don't add one the final day is in a group of it's own.

Answer (score 3):

Here’s an alternative approach that doesn’t use slider:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

test_df %>%
  mutate(period = cut(
    dates,
    seq(max(dates), min(dates), by = "-60 days"),
    right = TRUE
  )) %>%
  drop_na(period) %>%
  mutate(
    earliest_day_of_period = min(dates),
    latest_day_of_period = max(dates),
    day_span = latest_day_of_period - earliest_day_of_period + 1,
    .by = period
  ) %>%
  summarize(
    min_object_n = min(table(sample_colors, sample_objects)),
    .by = c(earliest_day_of_period, latest_day_of_period, day_span)
  )
#>   earliest_day_of_period latest_day_of_period day_span min_object_n
#> 1             2023-11-02           2023-12-31  60 days            6
#> 2             2023-09-03           2023-11-01  60 days            6
#> 3             2023-07-05           2023-09-02  60 days            5
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I appreciate this solution and wish I could co-check this as a resolution as well. This non-slider solution does nicely actually drop the partial period.